# Print debug message when Visual Studio Code task is run

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Running Visual Studio Code 1.39.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. Tasks are configured in `tasks.json` which can running by using `Terminal > Run Task...`.

Is it possible to print simple diagnostic messages to the in-built Terminal, for example `Running tasks 1...`, when a task is executed?

Same question launch tasks in `launch.json`.

Comment: Assuming you are using grunt that is executed with your task you could use `grunt.log.writeln()`.

Comment: `grunt`? That's a new one on me...is that built into VS Code?

Comment: Not directly built in, but VSC auto detects grunt or grunt task respectively. You have to install grunt (https://gruntjs.com) and configure a simple task. See here (https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) for infos about VSC task detection etc. (Grunt is also mentioned there).